# Do we have a policy on offensive language?

Tags: discussion, editing

I see someone's on an edit spree to remove expressions like "play your *ass* off" and "the *damn* trem arm" and " a piece of *shit* cello". Are these edits considered useful? Do we have a policy on what is considered "bad language", and whether it should be edited out?

Comment: Hi bob, we've already addressed this in a linked duplicate quite recently.

Comment: @Dom OK, thanks. I hadn't seen that.